# Is it ok to run SQL CE 4.0 under .net 3.5?

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I was wondering if anyone has run SQL CE 4.0 private deployment under a .net 3.5 application without issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this walkthrough](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/a-simple-guide-to-sql-compact-4/31).... it will .... and I quote, "work perfectly".  I started a small project myself and while I didn't finish it, I never ran into any show stopping bugs either.

Do note however some of the updates to the comments below his blog entry.  They point out some gotcha's (not related to .net 3.5 but how he was setting up CE).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this article. I actually have it working and running now under .net 3.5, however it seems that using the System.DataSqlServerCe.dll (v 4.0.0.0) under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Private creates an exception, and things only run smooth if I use the System.DataSqlServerCe.dll (v 4.0.0.1) from this directory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: The exception is throws when using System.DataSqlServerCe.dll from private directory: Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compact corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8482. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

Comment: Well, figured out my own question. The reason that only the one in desktop directory was working, is because I didn't name the 64 bit CE binaries in a folder named amd64. I had created the folders x86 and x64. x86 is correct, though x64 isn't.